# How to submit the browser type when download a web stream

Tags: c#, facebook, stream

My code is :

```
string result = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=123456789");
```

the result giving me supported browser.
body **class=\"unsupportedBrowser**

What i intend to do:
Download a source code from facebook for the particular page.

Problem encounter : 
I get the stream from facebook, facebook block me since i access from the apps due to this is not a valid browser.

**Expectation :** How i can submit the browser type like chrome to cheat the facebook as this is a valid browser.

Comment: Making a scraper are we?

Comment: [Web scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping)

Comment: Yes, actually i am trying to create a apps to track web shop item only. Dont make it complicate, i just want know how to cheat fb will do. As long i can view the source code it will be fine for me

Comment: FYI: Scraping FB pages (without their explicit prior permission) is forbidden by their ToS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add headers to the webclient object.  However, I prefer to go the HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse method of scraping since I believe it gives more options.

```
Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        Headers.Add("Cookie", "has_js=1");
        Headers.Add("DNT", "1");
        Headers.Add("Host", host);
        Headers.Add("Referer", url);
        Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0");
```

Comment: @.@ can you give me some example for that, i too long didnt touch http web request anymore, maybe you can provide the second options for people to read and learn it

Comment: Also be aware that `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` tells the server to deflate/compress the response using GZip, once you get the response you need to inflate/decompress it to get the actual response.

Comment: what is the host and referer value i should insert?

Comment: I think I used the base address e.g. facebook.com, and then the actual address e.g. facebook.com/1/222432.  But, I can't remember if that is right.  Maybe someone will add to that before I can take a look.  I will have to pull out the important parts for the httpwebresponse/request.  I have a class setup for response/request, but it also uses other dlls.

Comment: An exception occurred during a WebClient request.

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: {"The 'Host' header cannot be modified directly.\r\nParameter name: name"}

Comment: what i trying to comment everything others than user agent, it given me 404 not found

Comment: i am pretty believe that after assign the user agent the facebook will reject me

Comment: I can do some testing on it, but it probably won't be until tomorrow, and get you the other piece of code as well.  I may upload my other code to github for simplicity and provide a link to it.

Comment: fixed, facebook will return 404 if the link is not valid